# How to find relation between colors to recreate scheme?

Tags: color, hex

I'm messing around with some premade site designs and I really like the color balance of one, however the scheme is not the color I'm looking for. There are about 30 color variations in it.

Is there any way to find the numeric relation between the hex colors and then recreate that using a new base color?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your design template in Illustrator, you may try to create a Color Group and tweak it to your needs with `Edit Colors` feature.

Comment: +1 to `Edit Colors ...` you can also lock the relationship between colors so that you can move one "handle" or color and the others shift accordingly

Answer (score 0):

[kuler.adobe.com](https://kuler.adobe.com/) might help....

Edit added:
Kuler let's you choose a base color and reccomends other colors. You can also set your own color groups or browse ones created by others. It is also a quick reference for hex color codes and matching them to colors and other codes such as rgb and cmyk.

Comment: Hey! This came up on the review queue for Low Quality Posts because it's really short and just a link. It might end up getting deleted if you don't flesh out your answer a bit. How can using Kuler help answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, as you're talking about some website design, you might be seeing the RGB colors (as opposed to CMYK, I mean). Hence, if you wish to create the same combinations for some other base color, the only way as I see it is by manually swapping the values constituting the R, G and B color scales (though it might not lead to very impressive results).

> For example, if you're seeing a color that has a value, say `#FF7700` which has Red base followed by Green and finally Blue; if you wish to see how the color looks with a Green base, followed by Red and finally Blue, you can simply swap it as `#77FF00` which would have a Green base.
>   The same can be achieved in case you need to do it with the RGB color codes instead of HEX. For example, `RGB(255,119,0)` would be a Red base with Green added onto it, whereas `RGB(119,255,0)` would be the vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [palette](http://paletton.com/#uid=13x0u0k1T++00++00++a2++gt+A), on the site I choose a base color for instance my ***primary color***

```
$royal: #1a284d;
```

I use it to create a color scheme

[image]